# 1 dropdown menu with multiple and different outputs

Tags: javascript, html

So I've got a bit of a challange..
I'm trying to get 2 or 3 predefined outputs from a input value.
The code is below, but what I need to get working is that is I select ball_1, ball_2, ball_3 or ball_4 the VLAN and IP are diffrent.
ball_1 needs to output VLAN 12 and IP 32 but ball_2 needs to be VLAN 22 and IP 33 as for ball_3 and ball_4 the VLAN needs to remain empty..

```js
    function showData() {
      var theSelect = demoForm.demoSelect;
      var firstP = document.getElementById('firstP');
      var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');
      var thirdP = document.getElementById('thirdP');
      firstP.innerHTML = (theSelect.selectedIndex);
      secondP.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value) - (10);
      thirdP.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);
    }
```

```html
<form name="demoForm">
  <select name="demoSelect" onchange="showData()">
    <option value="zilch">Select:</option>
    <option value="32">ball_1</option>
    <option value="33">ball_2</option>
    <option value="84">ball_3</option>
    <option value="85">ball_4</option>
  </select>
</form>
<table class=table2>
  <tr>
    <td>bla</td>
    <td>VLAN</td>
    <td>IP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p id="firstP">&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="secondP">&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="thirdP">&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

bla is unused for now so that is not that important.

I've also found this bit of code which seems to better meet my needs but I can't get a dropdown menu to run the input value so it outputs a more or less correct value

```html
<form
    oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(300);y.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(400);">
        <table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="1"
        cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="a" value="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><output name="x" for="a b"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><output name="y" for="a b"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I've got some basic knowledge about hmtl and java I think but I can't get it to work properly or is it impossible?

thanks in advance
kind regards
Wouter
 
ps. I don't use a database and have 0 knowledge on how to build and run one, also where the site runs it's almost impossible to run a SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing drop down selected value correctly, Please look below working code.

Javascript function for accessing drop down selected value and setting IP and VLAN

```
function showData() {

        var ddlDemo = document.getElementById("ddlDemoSelect");
        var selectedValue = ddlDemo.options[ddlDemo.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selectedValue == 32) {
            document.getElementById('firstP').innerText = "bla";
            document.getElementById('secondP').innerText = "12";
            document.getElementById('thirdP').innerText = "32";
        }
        else if (selectedValue == 33) {
            document.getElementById('firstP').innerText = "bla";
            document.getElementById('secondP').innerText = "22";
            document.getElementById('thirdP').innerText = "33";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('firstP').innerText = "";
            document.getElementById('secondP').innerText = "";
            document.getElementById('thirdP').innerText = "";
        }
    }
```

Html. I have added Id for drop down to access it later on.

```
   <form name="demoForm">
     <select id="ddlDemoSelect" name="demoSelect" onchange="showData()">
       <option value="zilch">Select:</option>
       <option value="32">ball_1</option>
       <option value="33">ball_2</option>
       <option value="84">ball_3</option>
       <option value="85">ball_4</option>
     </select>
   </form>


 <table class=table2>
 <tr>
   <td>bla</td>
   <td>VLAN</td>
   <td>IP</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <p id="firstP">&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   <td>
     <p id="secondP">&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   <td>
     <p id="thirdP">&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```